# Django - No module named 'polls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Olá, estou começando a estudar Django (versão atual: 3.2.5), e segui este artigo na tentativa de configura-lo (versão consultada em 29/07/2021):
https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/django-instalacao-configuracao-e-escrevendo-seu-primeiro-app

Porém, ao executar o trecho citado no artigo:

> from polls.models import Question, Choice

Recebo:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'polls'

Revisei o passo a passo e não encontrei a causa.
Procurei no site da biblioteca Django, e lá encontrei um trecho citando:

> from .models import Choice, Question

Mas também não consegui importar desta forma.

Fico pensando que talvez o artigo esteja desatualizado, pois em outros trechos do artigo citava um método que já não é mais atual no Django, motivo pelo qual recebi aviso de 'deprecated'.
Mas, talvez tenha faltado alguma compreensão de minha parte, que também não estava no artigo, ou eu não estou vendo onde errei.

Alguém sabe onde está o problema/erro?

Comment: Nunca vi algo desta forma, sugiro por se tratar de um curso da ALura, você entre em contato com a plataforma, imagino que eles podem te ajudar de uma melhor forma.

Comment: Parece que na postagem foi ocultado algumas partes, esse import "from django.contrib import admin" é do modulo admin.py.. esse outro import "from polls.models import Question, Choice".. polls parece uma pasta.. seguindo a logica  Question, Choice é um model que esta no models..acho que foi daqui onde foi copiado o exemplo:https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: Esse tutorial está atualizado no site da documentação do Django. Sugiro seguir por lá. Está em português. Já fiz e está certinho. https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para essa parte. Mas aviso que devido a algumas divergências na versão atual do artigo da Alura, os próximos passos também não funcionaram (creio que faltam instruções/etapas foram puladas no artigo, por exemplo: É citado classes, que me parece que não foram criadas entre as etapas ali apontadas (Choice e Question)).
Obs.: Lancei a questão e o pedido de revisão do artigo no fórum da Alura, mas ainda não recebi retorno, portanto ficam as informações abaixo, que talvez possam ser úteis para outros que esbarrem no mesmo problema.

Fiz diversos testes e comparações, até entender que:
`from polls.models import Question, Choice` #Este trecho se parece muito com o do site do projeto Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.2/intro/tutorial02/), porém, lá a palavra "**polls**" foi o nome dado ao app criado. E no artigo da Alura, o nome do app foi citado como de livre escolha do aluno, conforme trecho abaixo:

> especifique o nome do aplicativo no campo Nome e selecione OK

Depois de pesquisar e ler as sugestões que citaram, entendi que quando criamos um app, usando o comando `python manage.py startapp nome_do_app`, ela gera um diretório na raiz do projeto, que se comporta como um pacote Python, com imports e tudo mais.

Ou seja, no artigo, onde consta:`from polls.models import Question, Choice`

O correto seria: `from nome_do_app.models import Question, Choice` #Substituindo 'nome_do_app' pelo nome escolhido pelo aluno.

Além disso, dependendo de como está configurado seu projeto e onde seu IDE buscará os pacotes python para import, pode ser necessário especificar o caminho completo, tal como exemplo:

```
from aprendendodjango.nome_do_app.models import Question, Choice
```

Obrigado